# Is there a scala version of Python's Mechanize?

Tags: scala, screen-scraping

I have used [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) in Python with great success.  However, I am trying to learn Scala.  I have an IRC bot that I would like to add some features to, mostly having to do with screen scraping web pages from our corporate intranet.  That requires being redirected to a corp-wide login page, then going to the destination, then having to possibly submit another login.

Does anyone know of something that I can use from Scala to get this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any Scala effort of similar functionality. Pending answers to the contrary, I advise you to look for *Java* libraries of similar functionality.

Comment: I found Prowser, which is a Java library that works a lot like mechanize.  So far I have been experimenting with that.

Answer (score 2):

The closest Java libraries I can think of are browser drivers. The most well-known are [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/). The latter also offers an in-process mode.

Since Selenium's API isn't all that pleasent to use, a couple of projects sprung-up with DSLish façades: [Selenium DSL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/seleniumdsl/) and [Selenium Inspector](http://seleniuminspector.org/).

A caveat is that they are all oriented towards testing of web application, so they might be lacking in features that attend your case.